# How to return result from a sequelize query thats wrapped in a function

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am building a service that creates a unique url for a user. 
It's supposed to do the following:

> - query database to see if the user already has the url and send it back
> - if user doesn't have the url create one using the user's first and last name
> - check the database if somebody else is using that combination of string and attach a 1, 2, or 3 depending on how many other users have the name (ie. JackBlack1, JackBlack2, etc.).
>
>   > I have one get route set up that checks for the url, if the user doesn't have one yet I want to send the result of a separate function call (for the sake of keeping the code modular). 
>   >     My problem is with the function. It does not return the url string. I am trying to save the url string to a variable that is initiated at the top of the function but it's not being saved from the sequelize query. 
>   >     Here is the route where I call the function:

```
router.get('/link', function(req, res) {

    db.user.find({where: {id: req.user.id} })

        .then(function(user){

        if (!user.addresslink) {
            res.send(createUserLink(req.user.id,req.user.firstName,req.user.lastName));
        } else {

        res.send(user.addresslink)

        }
    })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send('Internal database error.');
        })
})
```

And here is the createUserLink function:

```
function createUserLink(userId, first, last){
    var urlString = (first + last).toLowerCase();
    var userLink;
    var count;

    db.user.findAndCountAll({where: { addresslink: { $like:  'www.website.com/' + urlString } }
         }).then(function(result){

        if(result.count > 0) {
           count = result.count + 1;
           db.user.find({where: {id: userId} }).then(function(user){
                user.updateAttributes({
                    addresslink: 'www.website.com/' + urlString + count
                }).then(function(result){

                    userLink = result.addresslink

                    return userLink;
                })

           })

        } else {
            db.user.find({where: {id: userId} }).then(function(user){
                user.updateAttributes({
                    addresslink: 'www.website.com/' + urlString
                }).then(function(result){

                    userLink = result.addresslink

                    return userLink;
                })
           })
        }
    })
  return userLink ;            
}
```

I'm assuming the inability to return the created url from the function has to do with the asynchronous nature of the query. Do I need to add a query after the url has been created and then return it? This is my first question on here, so I apologize in advance if anything is inappropriate.

Comment: It's possible that indeed `findAndCountAll` is not returning before `res.send(createUserLink())`, you need to make `createUserLink` asynchronous and call res.send from the callback or promise.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the value being returned by your `createUserLink()`, you need to return the actual promise and attach a `.then()` to access the return value.

Currently, you're attempting to access the `userLink` returned as if it is a synchronous function where the function itself will return a value. The below example returns nothing to the client because `createUserLink()` returns `userLink` immediately which will be undefined.

**ie** `res.send(createUserLink(req.user.id,req.user.firstName,req.user.lastName));`

When dealing with promises this is not the case. Instead, the promise is  immediately returned in a pending state and needs to be awaited until the state is either fulfilled or rejected. When the promise has finished executing then you make access any returned values within a chained `.then()`

#### route

In the route, if a `user.addressLink` is `falsy` then we want to return the Promise returning function `createUserLink()`, else return the `user.addressLink`. When returning a value from within a `then()` the value returned us wrapped in a fulfilled Promise and the next `then()` is called or the value itself is returned to the closest Promise in the chain.

```
router.get('/link', function(req, res) {

    return db.user.find({where: {id: req.user.id} })
        .then(function(user){  
            if (!user.addresslink) 
                return createUserLink(req.user.id,req.user.firstName,req.user.lastName);
            else 
                return user.addressLink;
        })
        .then((userLink) => {
            return res.send(userLink);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send('Internal database error.');
        })
})
```

#### createUserLink

```
function createUserLink(userId, first, last){
    var urlString = (first + last).toLowerCase();
    var userLink;
    var count;

    return db.user.findAndCountAll({where: { addresslink: { $like:  'www.website.com/' + urlString } }})
     .then(function(result){
        if(result.count > 0) 
           count = result.count + 1;

        return db.user.find({where: {id: userId} });
      })
      .then(function (user) {
          let addressLink = 'www.website.com/' + urlString;

          if (count > 0)
            addressLink + count;

          return user.updateAttributes({ addresslink : addressLink });
      })
      .then(function(result){
          userLink = result.addresslink

          return userLink;
      })
}
```

For additional information about promises, [promisejs.org](https://www.promisejs.org/) is a great resource for learning how promises work. I recommend it if you want to learn more about promises.

Comment: Thank you @peteb! After posting this question I actually tried returning the query but my mistake was only returning the outer/main query and not the rest of the promises, which explains why it was not working.